# casperjs: can't get jquery to use global variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables, casperjs

I'm hoping this is a stupid question with an easy answer.

(I've googled for a day and a half without joy)

I am writing a casperjs script which changes a pulldown menu
I've dumbed down the test code to get to the crux of the problem
My test HTML is as follows:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:powderblue;">
    <form>
    <select id="down">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="vw">VW</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

A working Casperjs script using jquery:

```
casper.start("http://192.168.0.14/test.html", function(){
   //change the pulldown selection
   casper.then(function () {
        this.evaluate(function(){
            $('#down').val('vw').change();
        });
   });

   casper.then(function(){
           this.capture("screen.png");
   });
});
casper.run();
```

Now I want to parameterise the code, and use variables instead of strings for the *selector* and the *value*.   But this code does not work:

```
var x1='#down';
var y1='vw';

casper.start("http://192.168.0.14/test.html", function(){
   //change the pulldown selection
   casper.then(function () {
        this.evaluate(function(){
            $(x1).val(y1).change();
        });
   });

   casper.then(function(){
           this.capture("screen.png");
   });
});
casper.run();
```

This shouldn't be difficult (and probably isn't) but all combinations of "window." or square bracket notations have failed me.
jquery is refusing to play nice.

Please help, I didn't think this would put me out of my depth, but it clearly has

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
    this.evaluate(function(x1, y1){
        $(x1).val(y1).change();
    }, x1, y1);
```

Anything inside evaluate is sandboxed and you will need to pass in any params you want to use inside

Comment: That's it! You sir know what you are talking about.  Thank you very much